# Firebase rewrite rule not triggering Firebase Function

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to trigger the following function "dynamicMetaTagsUpdate" I have my Firebase rewrite setup like so

```
"rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "chart/**",
        "function": "dynamicMetaTagsUpdate"
      },
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
```

My apps URL are, the first view **https://viz.wiijii.co/#/create-chart**

and where I want the function to run **https://viz.wiijii.co/#/chart/?id=-MfJuHEtO2EQ3mpo682O**

This is the generated chart but it's not working am I missing something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are using URL fragments in the URL (`#`). Everything after the `#` in the URL is never sent to the server and cannot be used as the basis of Firebase Hosting rewrites. Instead, the URL should be e.g. https://viz.wiijii.co/chart/?id=-MfJuHEtO2EQ3mpo682O

Comment: Yea I had a feeling it was that

Comment: Thanks got it working need to find  away to remove the # in flutter